# How to save data on server without using database?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an application developed with Laravel. My software has settings that are used globally and should be available in all controllers (such as default information). I take this information from the database in the main controller every time a request is sent and save it in a variable.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class Controller extends BaseController
{

    protected $config;

    public function __construct()
    {
            $this->config= DB::table('config')->get();
    }


}
```

Is there a way to save and use this information without the intervention of a database? I don't want to use sessions.

It is better if a solution is introduced using laravel packages.

Thanks

Comment: What does `config` hold? Is it just a simple string, or a collection of data?

Comment: Is a collection @zlatan

Comment: Can you show us the output of that data, paste it in the question?

Comment: This is simple json. Just key value.

Comment: Values are array. Int or string.

Comment: You might be looking for https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache

You could use database, file or even redis for higher I/O

I't s hard to say if this is a good approach for your case, as there's a lack on context

It sounds like you want to cache, your settings to prevent retrieval on each request.
Cache should be good way. then but implement it, that cache always might be cleared.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You don't want to use sessions, you don't want to use a database - why do you want to persist something then?

Comment: What if you stored your config...in the [config directory](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration)? Am I missing something obvious as to why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you collection doesn't hold a lot of data, you can always put it inside your custom `config`. Create a `php` file inside your `app/config` directory, where you can put all your values like this:

```
<?php

return [
    'key1' => value1,
    'key2' => value2,
];
```

You can create any data structure here that you might need. Now, when you need to read single key from this data, you can use Laravel's `config()` helper:

```
$config = config('config_name.key');
```

If you want to get whole collection of the data, you can do it with the same `config()` helper, like this:

```
$config = config('app.config_name');
```

Hope that I understood your question right, and that this can lead you in right direction. You can read more about config on official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values).